# How can I get the sorted arrayList in HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have tried the following java code. But I can't get the correct output.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 

    {
ArrayList<HashMap<ArrayList<String>,Integer>> result=new ArrayList<>();     

    List<ArrayList<String>> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a")));
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a,b,c")));
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a,c")));
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("c")));
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("b,d")));
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("b")));

        ArrayList<Integer> value=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        value.add(1);
        value.add(5);
        value.add(3);
        value.add(4);
        value.add(2);
        value.add(1);

        HashMap<ArrayList<String>,Integer> map=new HashMap<ArrayList<String>,Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            map.put(list.get(i),value.get(i));
        }
        result.add(map);
        System.out.println(result);//output : [{[a]=1, [a,b,c]=5, [b]=1, [c]=4, [a,c]=3, [b,d]=2}]
    }
```

I got the output:

```
[{[a]=1, [a,b,c]=5, [b]=1, [c]=4, [a,c]=3, [b,d]=2}]
```

But, I want to get the sorted order by their word count such as:

```
[{[a]=1,[c]=4,[b]=1},{[a,c]=3, [b,d]=2},{ [a,b,c]=5}]
```

Comment: A `HashMap` does not have any order - if you want to have a ordered map, look at `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html`.

Comment: What is your initial requirement, we can find out a another suitable data structure rather than this? Can you edit the question with more information about your intent ?

Comment: It seems that your desired output `[{[a]=1,[c]=4,[b]=1},{[a,c]=3, [b,d]=2},{ [a,b,c]=5}]` is a list of three maps, according to the brackets. Why is that?

Comment: In the current format of this question, it's really not clear what you're actually trying to achieve: you've posted some code that evidently doesn't do what you require and it isn't obvious how a variant of it ever would (you mention "by their word count", but no line of the code you have posted appears to attempt to count words?). Can you explain in a couple of sentences of English what you are trying to achieve: what data do you need to take as input and how do you need it to be output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I think you need:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<List<String>, Integer>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

    put(mapList, Arrays.asList("a"),           1);
    put(mapList, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), 5);
    put(mapList, Arrays.asList("a", "c"),      3);
    put(mapList, Arrays.asList("c"),           4);
    put(mapList, Arrays.asList("b", "d"),      2);
    put(mapList, Arrays.asList("b"),           1);

    System.out.println(mapList); // Output: [{[a]=1, [b]=1, [c]=4}, {[a, c]=3, [b, d]=2}, {[a, b, c]=5}]
}

private static void put(List<Map<List<String>, Integer>> mapList, List<String> words, Integer number) {
    assert !words.isEmpty() : "Must be at least one word in list";

    // First, make sure our list of maps is long enough for the word list we're adding
    while(mapList.size() < words.size()) {
        mapList.add(new HashMap<>());
    }

    // Now, add the words and number to the appropriate map
    mapList.get(words.size() - 1).put(words, number);
}
```

Alternatively, we can construct an initial `Map` containing everything, then partition it by word count and sort the resulting collection. This approach means that if you don't have any word lists of a particular length, then no empty `Map` for holding such word lists will be added to the result (in the above solution, it would be). The code for this solution is a bit harder to understand - you may need to do sume reading around:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<List<String>, Integer> initial = new HashMap<>();

    initial.put(Arrays.asList("a"),           1);
    initial.put(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), 5);
    initial.put(Arrays.asList("a", "c"),      3);
    initial.put(Arrays.asList("c"),           4);
    initial.put(Arrays.asList("b", "d"),      2);
    initial.put(Arrays.asList("b"),           1);
    initial.put(Arrays.asList("v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), 99);

    List<Map<List<String>, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(
        initial.entrySet() // Get an unordered collection of entries
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                e -> e.getKey().size(), // Group by word list size...
                TreeMap::new, // ...into a sorted map...
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue) // ... collecting all values with the same word count into individual Maps
            ))
            .values() // Construct our ArrayList using the ordered collection of map values
    );

    System.out.println(result); // Output: [{[a]=1, [b]=1, [c]=4}, {[a, c]=3, [b, d]=2}, {[a, b, c]=5}, {[v, w, x, y, z]=99}]
    // Note that the above result doesn't contain an empty Map ('{}') for 4-word lists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sorting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    List<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a,b,c")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a,c")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("c")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("b,d")));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("b")));

    List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<>();
    value.add(1);
    value.add(5);
    value.add(3);
    value.add(4);
    value.add(2);
    value.add(1);

    HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        map.put(list.get(i), value.get(i));
    }
    Map<ArrayList<String>, Integer> sorted = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted((Map.Entry.<ArrayList<String>, Integer>comparingByValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

    System.out.println(map);//output : [{[a]=1, [a,b,c]=5, [b]=1, [c]=4, [a,c]=3, [b,d]=2}]
    System.out.println(sorted);//output : {[a]=1, [b]=1, [b,d]=2, [a,c]=3, [c]=4, [a,b,c]=5}
}
```

Comment: Efficient. But it doesn't seem to be the expected output.

Comment: It is as I get the author's question.
The initial requirement a little bit ambiguous.
  :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that a `HashMap` does not have any order. You can use eiter a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is sorted by natural ordering of its keys, or by a predefined comparator or a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which is sorted by insertion order.

Using a `TreeMap` you need to change your code just a little bit to get correct result:

```
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("a"),
        Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"),
        Arrays.asList("a", "c"),
        Arrays.asList("c"),
        Arrays.asList("b", "d"),
        Arrays.asList("b"));

List<Integer> value = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1);

Comparator<List<String>> comparator = Comparator.<List<String>>comparingInt(List::size)
        .thenComparing(List::hashCode);
TreeMap<List<String>, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    map.put(list.get(i), value.get(i));
}
```

With the comparator you tell the map to sort first by the size of the list and if multiple lists have the same size it uses `hashCode()` to order them. To the result will look like this:

```
{[a]=1, [b]=1, [c]=4, [a, c]=3, [b, d]=2, [a, b, c]=5}
```